# Is it wrong for Kafka server properties to be set such that the listeners and advertised listeners are the same?

Tags: apache-kafka

Before explaining my question I must confess *I absolutly do not understand what the difference is between* `listeners` *and* `advertised.listeners` *in the config*. From what I have read, both on other questions asked here and also in [this commonly cited blog post](https://www.confluent.io/en-gb/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/), they appear to be the same thing. I have tried genuinely very hard to read the documentation and understand both parameters - but I still currently don't understand them.

I don't understand what the intended use case for each parameter is or what the difference between them is, other than some vague answer about one being used for private networks and the other being used for public network addresses.

For context, I am currently running a Kafka cluster inside an internal, private network. The cluster is composed of 3 machines. I have also used Kafka in other contexts, such as a single instance running in a Docker container for testing purposes, and a cloud based solution. Again, in these instances it was never fully clear to me what the intended use case for either configuration parameter was, and with the cloud based Kafka offering, I never saw the configuration files.

With that said - here is my question:

I have a `server.properties` file setup like this:

```
process.roles=broker,controller

listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.0.1:9092,CONTROLLER://192.168.0.1:9093

inter.broker.listener.name=PLAINTEXT

advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.0.1:9092

controller.listener.names=CONTROLLER

listener.security.protocol.map=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT, ... etc ...
```

If I recall correctly, `PLAINTEXT` and `CONTROLLER` are just arbitrary strings, and they only have a "syntactic meaning" as part of the `listener.security.protocol.map`, where the `VALUE` part of the `KEY:VALUE` pairs has meaning. (The `KEY` part being just an arbitrary name like `CONTROLLER`.)

Anyway - so this Kafka instance listens on both ports `9092` and `9093`. Except that can't be quite right because I can't connect to `9093` using Conduktor. So I guess the "controller" port is for some other use and you're not supposed to connect to it using a consumer, producer, or application like Conduktor. (- maybe ?)

It doesn't seem to make a huge amount of sense to have `listeners` and `advertised.listeners` containing a listener which has the same name `PLAINTEXT` (which is an arbitrary string name), with the same ip address and port.

So what is going on here? Is my configuration nonsensical? what is the difference between these two parameters - because as much as I have tried to understand it I just don't.

Comment: Note: Listener "names" are arbitrary, but some listener names have special meanings. 
In a nutshell: if the name is a security protocol name, the security protocol name map can be omitted, because the security protocol will be inferred. If the name is NOT a security protocol, the security protocol map is required to map the name to the security protocol. More info here: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs

Answer (score 1):

A kafka client will connect to one node in the cluster, and that node will respond with the name/IP of each node in the cluster that the client can use to connect.  These names are what is contained in each server's `advertised.listeners` entry and does not necessarily need to be the same as the local IP/port of the server.

If `advertised.listeners` is not set, it defaults to whatever value was set for `listeners`.  So it's not wrong to set them to the same value, just redundant.

Let's say your kafka cluster sits in a private network, and the IP addresses are 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2, and 192.168.0.3, and they all listen on port 9092.  This private network sits behind a NAT that has a public IP with the name mykafka.public.cloud,

Suppose you want users from the public network to access your cluster.  The NAT will map ports 1111, 2222, and 3333 to 10.0.0.1:9092, 10.0.0.2:9092, and 10.0.0.3:9092 respectively.

The brokers will include the following configuration:

broker 1:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.0.1:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://mykafka.public.cloud:1111
```

broker 2:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.0.2:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://mykafka.public.cloud:2222
```

broker 3:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.0.3:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://mykafka.public.cloud:3333
```

Alternately, each of the brokers may have multiple IP address, for example:

- Broker 1: `192.168.0.1`, `10.0.0.1`
- Broker 2: `192.168.0.2`, `10.0.0.2`
- Broker 3: `192.168.0.3`, `10.0.0.3`

Presumably the `192.168.0.0/24` addresses would be connected to a different physical network to the `10.0.0.0/8` addresses, but it doesn't have to be.

Although these are both private networks (they are not routable), you want client applications to connect to the 10.0.0.x addresses and use the 192.168.0.x addresses for inter-broker communication. This has the advantage of segregating network traffic for two different purposes, resulting in greater scalability.

In this case you would use the following configs:

broker 1:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.0.0.1:9092
```

broker 2:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.0.0.1:9092
```

broker 3:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.0.0.1:9092
```

Here you can use `listeners` to bind to 0.0.0.0 and use `advertised.listeners` to give clients a specific IP to connect to.

Comment: This is a good answer, and I have upvoted it. It isn't quite the answer I was looking for, and I have added my own answer below. I also think it would be easier to understand with a small edit. I'm going to add that edit now, but if it doesn't make sense or isn't correct, please revert it and leave a comment explaining why.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've figured out part of an answer. For a reference on this, see *Effective Kafka* by Emil Koutanov.

One thing which didn't occur to me which perhaps should have is most servers will have multiple network interfaces. They will typically be connected to multiple (private) networks via these network interfaces, and therefore there will typically be a choice of IP address and physical network RJ45/SFP+ port which could be used for a Kafka related network traffic. (For the broker to communicate to other clients and brokers.)

- This is what `listeners` is for. It tells the Kafka program (executable process) which physical ports should be used. Obviously because TCP/IP networking provides a layer of abstraction to this, we usually think only about which IP addresses should be used for incoming and outgoing network traffic. Then we don't need to worry about the details of which physical network adapter is used. In summary, `listeners` specifies which network address to bind to for listening and where we expect to send and recieve data from and to.

I suppose it would probably have been possible to write the Kafka code such that one could specify something like `eth0` as the `listeners` parameter. But its not designed this way, and really this would be talking at the wrong level of abstraction.

---

`advertised.listeners` is a totally different concept. It does literally tell other people (clients, brokers) how to connect to Kafka. What is perhaps a bit confusing is that for most typical services like databases, there will be a single address which must be known in advance for a client program to connect to the database instance.

In the case of Kafka, a client needs to know **at least one** of the possible addresses to which it might connect. This is the concept of `bootstrap.servers`. Typically more than one address would be supplied to the bootstrap servers for redundancy/high availability. (In case one of those servers is currently down.)

- `advertised.listeners` is the address that a particular broker instance returns when it is asked how it can be contacted when it is configured as part of a cluster.
- If there is only one broker in the cluster, then `advertised.listeners` won't conceptually make a huge amount of sense because it will be exactly the same as the `bootstrap.servers` list, which will contain a single entry.
- Each broker instance has its own set of `advertised.listeners`, they are specific to each broker, but will be collected together, aggregated and returned to a client when the client first connects to one of the `bootstrap.server`s and asks for the full set of broker addresses.
- Because there may be multiple ways to connect (addresses) to a broker (for example and ipv4 address, an ipv6 address and a DNS address) `advertised.listeners` can contain multiple options.
- If the `bootstrap.servers` contains all possible addresses for all brokers in a cluster, then I suppose setting `advertised.listeners` becomes pointless. However, in a typical setup there would be a number (maybe 3-5) "default" brokers and others might be added dynamically over time for scaling or resiliancy purposes. (New brokers might be added to scale up the Kafka cluster as the volume of data grows.)

---

**Conclusion:** The configuration file which I showed in the original question is valid. It does the following:

- `listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.0.1:9092`: Tells the Kafka process to open a listening network socket on port 9092, bound to whichever physical interface is holding the address `192.168.0.1`.
- `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.0.1:9092`: Tells other clients to use the address `192.168.0.1:9092` when connecting to "me" (the broker).
- Since I gave an example of a setup for what you might assume is a single broker cluster, the `advertised.listeners` is a bit pointless. The same address must already have been set in the `bootstrap.servers` list on the client side, otherwise the client wouldn't know where to connect to when it starts up to ask for the full set of broker addresses in the cluster.
- **Caveat:** The `advertised.listeners` is not **totally pointless** and it is **still required configuration** because if it is not specified, the broker will default to using `listeners` for `advertised.listeners`. `listeners` **could be set to something like** `localhost:9092`, or `0.0.0.0:9092`, neither or which will be a valid address for a client to connect to, but would be perfectly fine for telling the Kafka process which network adapter to start a listening socket on.